# Which mode-line package(s) is/are most extendable?

Tags: themes, mode-line, powerline, spaceline, smart-mode-line

### My question:

Hi, lately I've been looking into various mode-line customization packages such as Smart Mode Line, Powerline, Spaceline, or Telephone Line. I'd like to write a package that works alongside one of the existing mode-line packages but modifies the faces it uses to render the modeline so that it blends in with the currently-enabled Custom Theme. **The problem is, I'm unsure of which mode-line package to write my camouflage package for, mostly because I don't know which package best supports what I'm trying to do.** I'm currently working on informing myself further, but I thought it couldn't ask to ask around a bit. (Sorry if this isn't the correct place to ask.) **Which mode-line package(s) would best suit my project?**

### Further explanation of what I'm trying to do:

I got the idea when I decided to try out a mode-line package. I decided to try Smart-Mode-Line first. One thing I have noticed about these packages (and about package faces in general**) is that in general, they do not integrate well with Emacs themes; when they attempt to, they sometimes result in illegible mode-line text. **I am aiming to write a special theming package (not merely another Custom Theme!) to use with one of the mode-line packages that will enable it to camouflage and blend in better with an Emacs theme,** rather than having to enable a separate Custom Theme on top of the actual enabled theme (which doesn't always work well).

#### My theming package will aim to do the following:

1. **Map the faces** that the package uses for rendering the mode-line to faces that are usually defined in Custom Theme packages (the mode-line faces, and the error faces, the stdout faces, comment faces, tooltip faces, etc).

   - I would also like to provide an interface (via Custom) for choosing which faces each mode-line face will inherit from. I have written a special "inherit-feature" function that allows specifying which features to inherit.
2. Enhance readability by automatically enhancing color contrast (using a function or two from shr.el, with some tweaks)
3. Further ensure readability by providing a way to fine-tune the results via a darkening/lightening coefficient for each of the colors used in the mode-line.
4. Allow users to specify face mappings for each Custom Theme (eg, "Use the Comment face foreground color as the ISearch mode-line background color when I'm using the Subatomic theme, but use the Helm-completion face instead when I'm using the Dracula theme.") that will be automatically used when a theme for which such specifications have been made is enabled. (At present, I assume that only one Custom Theme is enabled at a time. Subject to change.) **Naturally, this means that the package should ideally be able to detect or check for face changes more than just when it is loaded.**
5. I've noticed that with Vim Powerline, **the mode-line (or whatever they call it) changes content and color contextually**. I am more than willing to try to either implement this functionality as a supplement to an existing mode-line package; however, if it would involve a full fork and/or rewrite, I'll have to shelve this project for when I have more time to work on it. **This pretty much necessitates that the package be able to detect or check for face changes more than just when it is loaded, as well as provide a means to specify additional faces based on content type and, if at all possible, trigger certain changes with hook-run functions (rather than an idle timer).**

### Additional and background information

I don't care too much about how many different kinds of separators there are (as long as the options include "arrow" and "none") but I do care about **how the package handles window width***, truncation, and position of segments**; I don't care if you can add custom sections with arbitrary fixed text, but **I'd definitely  like to be able to specify position/alignment and spacing for things like buffer name, major mode name, minor mode lists, line/column position, file size, read-only-mode-ness, buffer modification, VCS integration, and EOL.**

So far, I like Powerline (despite the fact that it only uses a handful of face variables), but I'm not sure *exactly* how it differs from Spaceline and telephone-line yet. I'm still in the process of looking at the source code and trying to determine if I can write a theme for it that provides not only for more than that handful of faces (and add some context-specific ones!), or if a fork would be necessary to do so. telephone-line is much better documented, and offers more user-accessible faces, but I'm not sure how robust its alignment and truncation is.

** *I've noticed that while most packages try to have their faces inherit from built-in faces with similar functions (which Custom Theme designers are likely to include specifications for in their themes), but some unfortunately do not.*

*** *I recently attempted to write a function that would update SML's min and max buffer-/file-name-width when the window (NOT just frame) changed size. However, it seems that it only checks the value of the min-width (which also specifies max-width if it's a `( . )` pair) once (on init). I would also have liked to be able to use my own name truncation function.*

Comment: This "question" is not a good fit for Stack Exchange, IMO. As phrased, it is currently too broad. Please consider asking a *specific* question, perhaps one (or two or three...) that might lead you toward your broader goal. Alternatively, there are other web sites where such a broad question is not off-topic. Reddit > Emacs, for instance, might help you find some pointers that will get you started in your exploration.

Comment: @Drew Good idea. Thanks for the pointers!